# Load modal content not before modal is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, so I have a simple CSS-styled modal, shown upon hitting a button via jScript. This is the jScript:

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

[SOURCE](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal)

Since I will have a LOT of these things on the page, it is neccessary that the contents (mostly huge pictures) of the modals do not load until the respective modal is actually displayed. As far as I know I will need to do this via jQuery but I can't seem to find any good snippet for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you have an array of image URLS, you can append an image element dynamically when modal displays block. if you have please provide it on your post if how this image URLs will be pulled.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set image `source` when you click the `button` in order to `show` modal.

You can set image `source` with `javascript`, using `document.querySelector()` method.

```
document.querySelector('.modal-content img').src=src;
```

Or, with `jquery` library, using `.attr()` method.

```
$('.modal-content').find('img').attr('src',src);
```

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxPY1VmPOqgQip3ku3TUrx5g_uryG63qlN9iDBaXkWkTrT466fqA";
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    //document.querySelector('.modal-content img').src=src;
    $('.modal-content').find('img').attr('src',src);
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <img src=""/>
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**. The solution with more images.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxPY1VmPOqgQip3ku3TUrx5g_uryG63qlN9iDBaXkWkTrT466fqA";
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    $('.modal-content').find('img').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
  for(i=0;i<100;i++){
     $('.modal-content').append('<img src=""/>');
  }
  $('img').attr('src',src);
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is actually on of the solution, however the problem is how will he pull those images. but neverthless, cool!

Comment: @Roljhon, i will update in few seconds with multiple images.

Comment: Would just appending an <img> tag actually download the image? My feeling tells me it would just "confuse" the browser and not display an image. Just asking, I cant try right now.

Comment: no..append only adds a new image in `modal-content`.I set image source with `attr()` method.

Comment: The required `src` attribute specifies the URL of the image. Note: When a web page loads; it is the browser, at that moment, that gets the image from a web server and inserts it into the page.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai that's what I meant. I have no problem with populating the modals. The problem is preventing to load the image until the modal is displayed and just THEN download the actual picture.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. Images are loaded only when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great plugin for this problem called imagesLoaded by desandro:

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

The plugin is used like this (much better documentation on the GitHub page):

`$('#container').imagesLoaded( function() {
  // images have loaded
});`

Also here is a [jQuery demo](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/pjVMPB), and here is a [vanilla JS demo](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/vNrBGz).

Comment: This reads to me as if it just calls an event WHEN the images are loaded? If so, I need to clarify: I want the images NOT to be loaded until the modal they're in is shown.

Comment: Oh my bad, I misunderstood. You could use jQuery and do something this this:

`var $image = $("img").first();
var $downloadingImage = $("<img>");
$downloadingImage.load(function(){
  $image.attr("src", $(this).attr("src")); 
});
$downloadingImage.attr("src", "http://an.image/to/aynchrounously/download.jpg");`

Comment: @cnzac why doing like this? `$("<img>");`, its actually wrong,maybe you mean this `$("img")`? you need to click the `<>` icon from the editor and show how it will be used on the OP

Comment: I'm sorry I was paraphrasing from this tutorial: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-asynchronously-loading-image